# collapsed navbar has margin between first drop down list element main menu and right margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the long title, but as stated there is a margin between the first dropdown element and the main navbar when the window is collapsed. There is also an ugly margin on the right side that is unwelcome. I have included my HTML and CSS, although I had another problem with the dropdown (same HTML and CSS) and Venugopal provided me with the correct answer and a jsfiddle demo so I will link to both as well.

HTML:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-    toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"  aria-    expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h2>LOGO</h2></a></div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">



    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right links">
      <li><a href="#"><h5>Link 1</h5></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><h5>Link 2</h5></a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown" data-parent="#accordion" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"    aria-expanded="false"><h5>Dropdown</h5></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><span class="label label-danger  home-label" >Give us a call! &nbsp;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
}
body{
padding-top: 120px; 
background-color:#34A0CD;
}


.navbar-default{
height:120px;
}
.navbar-header, .navbar-brand{
height:120px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;   
}
home-label{
font-size:17px;
margin-right:35px;

}
.navbar-nav li span{
font-size:17px;
margin-right:35px;
line-height:130px;
}

#topFixedNavbar1{
height:120px;
}
.links{
height:120px;

}
.navbar-nav li a{
padding-top:11px;
padding-bottom:8px;
}
.navbar-nav li a h5{
line-height:80px;
}
.dropdown li a {
line-height:30px;

}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.dropdown li a{
    line-height:30px;
}

.collapse.navbar-collapse{
    width:100%;

}
.links li a{

    width:100%;
}
.navbar-nav li.open a h5,.navbar-nav li.open a h5:hover {
    color: black;
    background: 0 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.navbar-default                                 navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus
{
background-color: gray;
}
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent ;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);

}

.navbar-collapse.in {
overflow-y: visible;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;

}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;

}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav li a h5{
line-height: 15px;
background-color: gray;
color: #F1E9E9;     
}
.navbar-nav li a span{
    line-height:15px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.navbar-nav li a{
    background-color:gray;
    width:100%;
}


.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block!important;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}

}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se6ug2q5/2/) provided by Venugopal with the collapsed navbar; you should see the margin between the first list element and the right side of the page when the toggle is clicked. Thank you all for your help, this is my fourth question on customizing my navbar, changing the brand and height really messes things up! (for a rookie anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling, concurrent with the discovery of how powerful Dev Tools in Chrome really is, I discovered Bootstrap provides a margin of 7.5px top and bottom on the **ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right** class as well as a right margin and some padding on **#topFixedNavbar1.navbar-collapse.collapse.in**. These problems all arose because I wanted my dropdown to completely span the width of the screen and for no background space between the drop down menu and the navbar itself when collapsed. You'd think there'd be a more explicitly-written way to alter this but at least it is done and over with, phew!